# Почему массив пустой?

Tags: vue.js

я получаю данные либо прямо из state либо как пропс из родительского компонента

```
countryId: state => state.updateCampaign.data.countryIds,
countryId: {
            type: Array,
            require: false,
            default: function () { return [] },
        }
```

и использую в функции для установки дефолтного значения  в мультиселекте

```
defaultData() {
            console.log(this.countryId)
            for (let i = 0; i < this.countryId.length; i++) {
                this.country.push(this.countryList[this.countryId[i] - 1])
            }
        }
```

```
mounted() {
        this.defaultData()
    }
```

плагин в хроме видит эти значения в компоненте, но при перезагрузке страницы или когда первый раз на нее заходишь  this.countryId будет пустым, с чем может быть связанно подобное поведения в гуле ничего такого не нашел,

Comment: При `{ countryId: <значение1>, countryId: <значение2> }`, первое объявление свойства (с `значение1`) будет отброшено интерпретатором как мертвый код - будет выполнено только последнее.

Comment: это я для примера показал, countryId всегда приходит нормально, по крайне мере в vue плагин его видит, но в некоторых случаях в консоли  он показывается пустым

Comment: _«это я для примера показал»_ - ну, значит ССЗБ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть такое что props не успевает прити когда запускают метод defaultData(), поэтому мой совет записать ее в computed и запускать метод когда будет computed.